# Changing Coherence function from float to fixed point

Tags: audio, power-spectral-density, c, fixed-point, coherence

I want to calculate the coherence between two audio signals. After referring a few websites, I found that the coherence is calculated by using the equation $(1)$ which is as follows

$$\rm Coherence = \frac{Cross \ PSD}{PSD_{signal_1}\cdot  PSD_{signal_2}}\tag{1}$$

So, I have written a function that calculates coherence which is follows

(`ftemp1` and `ftemp2` variables correspond to real and imaginary values of cross PSD function)

```
void coherence_calc(float* real,  
             float * imag,     
             float * psd1,    
             float * psd2,    
             float * output,     
             int length)
{
   float ftemp1 = 0.0f,ftemp2 = 0.0f,ftemp3 = 0.0f;

   for (i = 0; i < Length; i++)
   {
       ftemp1 = real[i] * real[i];
       ftemp2 = imag[i] * imag[i];
       ftemp3 = psd1[i] * psd2[i];
        
       if( ftemp3 == 0.0f)
          output[i] = (ftemp1 + ftemp2) / (ftemp3 + 1e-12);
       else
          output[i] = (ftemp1 + ftemp2) / ftemp3;  
           
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this function into a fixed point code. I observed that the input and output float values to and from this function are always in the range of $(-1, 1)$. Just to note, some of the values of `ftemp1`, `ftemp2`, `ftemp3` in the float code are in the range of `10e-20` and `10e-25`.

After converting this function into a fixed point, I observed a lot of deviation between the float code output and the fixed code output due to one particular issue which is as follows.

The minimum Q format I have to use for `ftemp1`, `ftemp2`, `ftemp3` variables is $\rm Q26.6$ format (in fixed-point code). So, when the values of the above-said variables are less than $1/64$, the corresponding values in the fixed-point code are becoming $0$, which results to $0$ (when both `ftemp1` and `ftemp2` are $0$) or infinity (when `ftemp3` is $0$) as the overall output. Is there any way to overcome this problem i.e. to reduce the deviation between the outputs?

Note: I have tried scaling down and scaling up the inputs passing to this function, but neither of the methods didn't solve the problem.

Comment: If you favour accuracy and you *can* scale your numbers, why not reduce the integer word length to increase the fractional word length a bit?

Comment: @A_A No. I can't reduce the number of bits assigned for the integer part because I require at least 25 bits to store the ftemp1, ftemp2 and ftemp3 variables (excluding sign bit). The dynamic range of these variables is very high i.e. it varies from very small values (1e-20) to very large values (few lakhs).

Comment: @rkc your dynamic range should be 2³², no matter where you put the  point?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok. In that case, how to deal with very small float values? As I mentioned above, very small float values are creating a problem in my case.

Comment: Since you are trying to use Fixed Point, what sort of CPU is this to run on? There are a couple of things you can do to manage the dynamic range but none of it "equates" the fixed point range to the floating point range.

Comment: As of now, I am running the code on a windows machine. Later, I want to put the working model (on the windows machine) on the raspberry pi.